# How to Install postgresql-client-11 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, backup, ubuntu, pg-dump

I need to use the `pg_basebackup`/`pg_dump` program on an Ubuntu 18.04 system to connect to a remote PostgreSQL 11.6 server.

However, the current system only contains `pg_basebackup` 10.10 and the remote database is using PostgreSQL 11.6. Running `pg_basebackup` give the error

> pg_basebackup: incompatible server version 11.6

Tried to install the correct version of `pg_basebackup` using the command:

```
apt install postgresql-client-11
```

but the apt package is not found. Only `postgresql-client`, `postgresql-client-10` and `postgresql-client-common` are available the system's apt repos.

**Question:** How can we install the correct version of `pg_basebackup` without having to copy it over from the remote database server, and without installing PostgreSQL 11.6 on this machine?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Install it from PostgreSQL's own apt repository, adapted from [these instructions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).

```
sudo apt-get install curl ca-certificates gnupg
curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install postgresql-client-11
pg_basebackup -V
```

> pg_basebackup (PostgreSQL) 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-1.pgdg18.04+1)

Comment: This also works with version 12 (using `sudo apt install postgresql-client-12`)